# Looking for a scalar function to find the last occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: sql, db2

Table `FOO` has a column `FILEPATH` of type `VARCHAR(512)`. Its entries are absolute paths:

```
FILEPATH
------------------------------------------------------------
file://very/long/file/path/with/many/slashes/in/it/foo.xml
file://even/longer/file/path/with/more/slashes/in/it/baz.xml
file://something/completely/different/foo.xml
file://short/path/foobar.xml
```

There's ~50k records in this table and I want to know all distinct filenames, not the file paths:

```
foo.xml
baz.xml
foobar.xml
```

This looks easy, but I couldn't find a DB2 scalar function that allows me to search for the last occurrence of a character in a string. Am I overseeing something?

I could do this with a recursive query, but this appears to be overkill for such a simple task and (oh wonder) is extremely slow:

```
WITH PATHFRAGMENTS (POS, PATHFRAGMENT) AS (
  SELECT
    1,
    FILEPATH
  FROM FOO

UNION ALL

  SELECT
    POSITION('/', PATHFRAGMENT, OCTETS) AS POS, 
    SUBSTR(PATHFRAGMENT, POSITION('/', PATHFRAGMENT, OCTETS)+1) AS PATHFRAGMENT
  FROM PATHFRAGMENTS
)
SELECT DISTINCT PATHFRAGMENT FROM PATHFRAGMENTS WHERE POS = 0
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can use regular expressions with xquery, in a SQL.

Comment: @AngocA: Thanks, pointing me to XQuery was a valuable hint - see my own answer.

Comment: Great! I did not have DB2 at hand to help you. However, I see that you researched and gave a very good answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`LOCATE_IN_STRING()` scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054098.html). This is what Info Center has to say if you use a negative start value:

> If the value of the integer is less than zero, the search begins at
>   LENGTH(source-string) + start + 1 and continues for each position to
>   the beginning of the string.

Combine that with the [`LENGTH()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000818.html) and [`RIGHT()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000844.html) scalar functions, and you can get what you want:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(
         FILEPATH
        ,LENGTH(FILEPATH) - LOCATE_IN_STRING(FILEPATH,'/',-1)
    )
FROM FOO
```

Comment: That **is** in fact what I was looking for. I have no idea why I couldn't find that function myself... It appears that the DB2 information center is not as informative as its name suggests...

Comment: Too bad this function is not available on DB2 running on AS/400

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by taking advantage of the power of DB2s [XQuery](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrcontainer.html) engine. The following worked for me (and fast):

```
SELECT DISTINCT XMLCAST(
     XMLQuery('tokenize($P, ''/'')[last()]' PASSING FILEPATH AS "P")
   AS VARCHAR(512) )
FROM FOO
```

Here I use [tokenize](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfntkz.html) to split the file path into a sequence of tokens and then select the last of these tokens. The rest is only conversion from SQL to XML types and back again.

Comment: Tobias Heinric: Can you please give a simple example on how to use tokenize for splitting a simple string. For e.g. I want to tokenize "abc,xyz,pqr" on "," in a single sql. The result of the query should be three rows viz. abc, xyz and pqr.

Comment: The following query is working: select xmlcast(xmlquery('tokenize($P,",")[last()]' passing 'abc,pqr,xyz' as "P") as varchar(512)) from sysibm.dual  giving result as xyz, but select xmlcast(xmlquery('tokenize($P,",")' passing 'abc,pqr,xyz' as "P") as varchar(512)) from sysibm.dual   doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the problem from the OP was already solved but I decided to post the following anyway to hopefully help others like me that land here.

I came across this thread while searching for a solution to my similar problem which had the exact same requirement but was for a different kind of database that was also lacking the `REVERSE` function.

In my case this was for a *OpenEdge (Progress)* database, which has a slightly different syntax.  This made the `INSTR` function available to me that [most Oracle typed databases offer](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr).

So I came up with the following code:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING( 
    foo.filepath, 
    INSTR(foo.filepath, '/',1, LENGTH(foo.filepath) - LENGTH( REPLACE( foo.filepath, '/',  '')))+1, 
    LENGTH(foo.filepath))
FROM foo
```

However, for my specific situation (being the *OpenEdge (Progress)* database) this did not result into the desired behaviour because replacing the character with an empty char gave the same length as the original string. This doesn't make much sense to me but I was able to bypass the problem with the code below:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING( 
    foo.filepath, 
    INSTR(foo.filepath, '/',1, LENGTH( REPLACE( foo.filepath, '/',  'XX')) - LENGTH(foo.filepath))+1, 
    LENGTH(foo.filepath))
FROM foo
```

---

Now I understand that this code won't solve the problem for **T-SQL** because there is no alternative to the `INSTR` function that offers the `Occurence` property.

Just to be thorough I'll add the code needed to create this scalar function so it can be used the same way like I did in the above examples.

```
  -- Drop the function if it already exists
  IF OBJECT_ID('INSTR', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION INSTR
  GO

  -- User-defined function to implement Oracle INSTR in SQL Server
  CREATE FUNCTION INSTR (@str VARCHAR(8000), @substr VARCHAR(255), @start INT, @occurrence INT)
  RETURNS INT
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @found INT = @occurrence,
            @pos INT = @start;

    WHILE 1=1 
    BEGIN
        -- Find the next occurrence
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@substr, @str, @pos);

        -- Nothing found
        IF @pos IS NULL OR @pos = 0
            RETURN @pos;

        -- The required occurrence found
        IF @found = 1
            BREAK;

        -- Prepare to find another one occurrence
        SET @found = @found - 1;
        SET @pos = @pos + 1;
    END

    RETURN @pos;
  END
  GO
```

To avoid the obvious, when the `REVERSE` function is available you do not need to create this scalar function and you can just get the required result like this:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(
    foo.filepath, 
    LEN(foo.filepath) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(foo.filepath))+2, 
    LEN(foo.filepath))
FROM foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it in a single statement:

```
select distinct reverse(substring(reverse(FILEPATH), 1, charindex('/', reverse(FILEPATH))-1))
from filetable
```

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `REVERSE` function in DB2 either.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION reverse(input VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) 
 CONTAINS SQL DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
 RETURN WITH rec(i, rev, org) AS 
 (VALUES (1, CASE WHEN input IS NOT NULL  THEN CAST('' AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
 ELSE NULL END, input) 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT i + 1, substr(org, 1, 1) || rev, substr(org, 2, length(org) -1) 
 FROM rec 
 WHERE i < 1000 AND org <> '' AND org IS NOT NULL) 
 SELECT rev FROM rec WHERE org = '' OR org IS NULL; 

values (reverse('Hello World')); 

http://www.databaseteam.org/9-db2/78f5eeb93de4714b.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the idea. However, the syntax you're using in your answer (not in your comment) simply does not work. At least not for DB2 v9.7, but I doubt it'll work on newer systems either. Also note that the XQuery function `reverse` reverses a sequence and a string (such as `FILEPATH`) is not per se considered a sequence by DB2 (at least that's what I observed). You'd have to convert it to codepoints first and then back to string after reversing.